# Is it possible to have JavaScript animations only run on desktop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I'm currently working on a website using **React.js** and **Framer Motion**. Within this website is something similar to an image carousel.

[image]

When an image is toggled on, it expands to show the full width of the image. That is also to say when toggled off, the image shrinks back to its original size.

The code looks like the following below:

```js
import "./projectStyle.css";
import { useState, useEffects } from "react";
import { animate, motion } from "framer-motion";

const variants = {
  open: { width: "40rem" },
  closed: {}
};


export default function Project(props) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <motion.div
      animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
      variants={variants}
      className="projectWrapper mobile"
      onClick={ () => setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen) }
    >
      <div className="overlayContainer">
        <img src={props.siteImage} alt={props.altText} />
        <div className="overlay"></div>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Currently the image expands on mobile, tablet, and desktop, I'm curious to know if it's possible to have this animation work **only** on desktop. And if so, how?

Do I need to have a variable that tracks the current width of the window? And if the width becomes a certain size stop the animation?

If this question has already been answered, it'd be great to be directed towards that solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

yeah it's possible!

but how?
we have a object called navigator in browser
navigator have a property named appVersion return some detail about client os!
i tried it on my pc and my android and i got the diffrent result so its work!
pc : `'5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'`

android : `5.0 (Linux; Android 11; 2201117TG Build/RKQ1.211001.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/114.0.5735.196 Mobile Safari/537.36` 
so do this (do some Creativity things to create a better code than my code but anyway) :

```
const osClient= navigator.appVersion

if(osClient.indexOf("Win") != -1) //do code 

if(os.Client.indexOf("Mac") != -1) //do code 

//and do this on every os or do some Creativity!
```